# 2 dimensional table, why there is NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a code like this:

```
   public class SumNum {
    int inside;
    SumNum(int inside){
        this.inside = inside;   
        }
    public int getInside(){
        return inside;
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SumNum[][] tab = new SumNum[3][];
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tab.length; j++) {
            tab[i][j] = new SumNum(i);
            System.out.println(tab[i][j]+" "+tab[i][j].hashCode()+" "+tab[i][j].getInside());
        }
    }

}
```

}

I didn't set size of second dimension array. There shouldn't be array out of bound exception, because second loop index (`j`) is limited by length of array and Ok, it works.

The question is: why there's `NullPointerException`? Object should be created, so it's has not "null" value.

Comment: You should be using the debugger (or just print statements) to check your assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one dimension defined here:

tab[i][j]

When you try to get  j = 1 you try to access to null object. This is why you get NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

Unless a second array dimension is specified in the 2D array `tab`, an array containing `null` values will be created using which is the default unassigned value for elements in an `Object` array. Using

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tab));
```

will produce

```
[null, null, null]
```

Attempting to assign the value

```
tab[i][j] = new SumNum(i);
```

produces the `NPE`

Answer (score 1):

Because second dimension is not defined then access like:

```
tab[i][j]
```

for arguments like i = 0, and j = 1 will produce obvious NullPointerException as you try to access to null object.

According to your code array tab will be as follows:

[null, null, null]

Answer (score 1):

There is `NullPointerException` because :

```
tab[i][j] = new SumNum(i);
```

attempt to access null array object

j is not defined in `SumNum[][] tab = new SumNum[3][];`

if you change your code to:

```
SumNum[][] tab = new SumNum[3][3]; it will work.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are declaring the size of one dimension only, you need to allocate memory for the other dimension by specifying its size. The 'Additional line' below will fix you problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SumNum[][] tab = new SumNum[3][];
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {

        //Additional line
        tab[i] = new SumNum[ANYSIZE_HERE];

        for (int j = 0; j < tab.length; j++) {
            tab[i][j] = new SumNum(i);
            System.out.println(tab[i][j]+" "+tab[i][j].hashCode()+" "+tab[i][j].getInside());
        }
    }

}
```